# Facebook login fail

Tags: ios, facebook

I followed Facebook Scruptious example and have an issue with authorizing the app.

When I run the app and the user is logged into the native Facebook app, the authorization of the app works perfectly - the user is taken to the native app, authorizes and is returned to the app. However, if the user is not logged into the facebook app, he is asked to log in, but then authorization is not requested and the user remains in the Facebook app. Questions:
1. Is this a FB bug and is there any way to resolve it?
2. I pressed the home button and opened the app again - I expected

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

to take care of the failed authorization by retrying, but nothing happened.

Any advice on getting this resolved would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the update after create the Session (log in)

Do you have something like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

// this button's job is to flip-flop the session from open to closed
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    // if a user logs out explicitly, we delete any cached token information, and next
    // time they run the applicaiton they will be presented with log in UX again; most
    // users will simply close the app or switch away, without logging out; this will
    // cause the implicit cached-token login to occur on next launch of the application
    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

} else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        // Create a new, logged out session.
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }

    // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                     FBSessionState status, 
                                                     NSError *error) {
        // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
        [self updateView];
    }];
}
```

Remember to do that `[self updateView];`

Assumming that your **UpdateView** is something like this:

```
- (void)updateView {
// get the app delegate, so that we can reference the session property
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {        
    // valid account UI is shown whenever the session is open
    [self.buttonLoginLogout setTitle:@"Log out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    [self.textNoteOrLink setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@", appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken]];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"inicio" sender:self];
} else {        
    // login-needed account UI is shown whenever the session is closed
    [self.buttonLoginLogout setTitle:@"Log in" forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    [self.textNoteOrLink setText:@"Login to create a link to fetch account data"];        
}

 }
```